# Error message in checkout step

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm getting the following error on the return page of my off-site payment:

```
#1 ... /httpdocs/core/modules/editor/editor.module(554): _drupal_error_handler(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '... /httpdocs/ ...', 554, Array)
#2 ... /httpdocs/core/modules/editor/editor.module(384): _editor_get_file_uuids_by_field(NULL)
#3 [internal function]: editor_entity_update(Object(Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order))
#4 ... /httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(402): call_user_func_array('editor_entity_u...', Array)
#5 ... /httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(169): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll('entity_update', Array)
#6 ... /httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(730): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->invokeHook('update', Object(Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order))
#7 ... /httpdocs/modules/contrib/commerce/src/CommerceContentEntityStorage.php(88): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeHook('update', Object(Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order))
#8 ... /httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(470): Drupal\commerce\CommerceContentEntityStorage->invokeHook('update', Object(Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order))
#9 ... /httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(615): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPostSave(Object(Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order), true)
#10 ... /httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(395): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPostSave(Object(Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order), true)
#11 ... /httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php(820): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object(Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order))
#12 ... /httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity.php(391): Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save(Object(Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order))
#13 ... /httpdocs/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/checkout/src/Plugin/Commerce\CheckoutFlow\CheckoutFlowBase.php(130): Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save()
#14 ... /httpdocs/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/payment/src/Controller/PaymentCheckoutController.php(88): Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutFlow\CheckoutFlowBase->redirectToStep('complete')
#15 [internal function]: Drupal\commerce_payment\Controller\PaymentCheckoutController->returnPage(Object(Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
```

(any stack beyond this is, afaik, Drupal boiler plate)

Digging into editor.module, obviously the `original` property of my order entity is NULL, and that causes the error.

Does this indicate that my order has not been updated, and does not need saving? As in, I should just patch the CheckoutFlowBase class to check if the `original` property is set, and if so, save?

Or is the fix going to have to be more complicated?

Comment: It sounds like you're double saving the order (triggering an $order->save() in a presave hook or an event subscriber for a transition). You'll want to find & remove that.

Comment: I subscribe to "commerce_order.place.post_transition" to send order data to Navision. In this event I save the Navision order id int a custom order field. Could that be the cause? I would have expected the post_transition to be the right event for this type of logic.

Comment: Yes, that is the cause. You're not allowed to save the order yourself. Drupal limitation, not ours. Switch to a pre_transition, that should allow you to modify the order before the system saves it.

Comment: I reshuffled my module and hooked up to the pre_transition. Everything appears to work now. Could you post your comment as an answer? Then this questions can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error most commonly occurs if an order is being double-saved, by calling $order->save() within a hook_entity_presave() or a matching event, including pre/post transition events.

If you need to modify the order during a state transition, do it in a pre-transition event and let the system take care of the rest.